# CSS transform `rotate` value from formula?

Tags: css, sass

As shown in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vcpLorxe/14/), I have a custom underline that uses `transform: skew(-30deg) rotate(-2deg);`.

How can I replace the -2 with a formula that uses the width?

E.g. `[width in pixels] * .004 - 2.4`

I never know the width ahead of time because the quotes and fonts can change.

```scss
.underlined {
  $lineColor: #4ffe25;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  &::before {
    background-color: $lineColor;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: calc(99% + 0px);
    height: 15%;
    left: 0;
    top: 95%;
    z-index: -1;
    transform: skew(-30deg) rotate(-2deg); /* How to use a formula for the `rotate` value?  */
  }
}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: What is the spec of what is wanted? Is it that the green line starts say n pixels below the baseline and always ends up on the baseline regardless of how wide the quote is?

Comment: @AHaworth That's a fair way of thinking about it. Thanks.

Comment: Ideally it would have some curvature to it, where the middle is bowed higher than the tips. I found https://codepen.io/shadeed/pen/OeNbMO , and the randomness concept is awesome, but it looked like it would be a pain to get that working in a simple React frontend.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a supported [angle unit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/angle#units) that takes dynamic radius into consideration. However, you could consider using `clip-path` instead. The use of [length-percentage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length-percentage) [refers to the length and height of the element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_shapes/Basic_shapes#the_reference_box).

```css
.underlined {
  --line-color: #4ffe25;
  position: relative;
}

.underlined::before {
  background-color: var(--line-color);
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 30%;
  z-index: -1;
  clip-path: polygon(2% 85%, 100% 55%, 98% 70%, 0% 100%);
  transform: skew(-20deg);
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 600px">
  <div class="content" style="font-size: 80%; line-height: 170%;">
    <div class="quote">
      <div class="line">
        “In the paycheck world,
        <span class="underlined" style="font-size:30px"> there used to be a saying: </span><br>
      </div>
      <div class="line">dress for the job you want, not the job you have.<br> </div>
      <div class="line">The analogous idea in the free agent world is:<br> </div>
      <div class="line"> learn to exercise the <span class="underlined"> freedoms you might acquire</span>,<br> </div>
      <div class="line">not just the freedoms you have.” </div>
    </div>
    <div class="person"><span class="underlined" style="font-size:10px">- Venkatesh Rao </span></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is cool. Thanks for sharing! I wonder if this won't get me what I want because I'd like the line to get closer to flat for wider phrases. Thanks, though!

Answer (score 2):

You could play around with gradient background images as they 'know' about coming to/going from corners and don't depend on your knowing the width in advance.

Here's an example which alters depending on font size.

```html
<style>
  .container {
    font-size: 24px;
  }
  
  .underlined {
    --lineColor: #4ffe25;
    --thickness: 0.1em;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    width: fit-content;
  }
  
  .underlined::before {
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 0.4em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1em;
    left: 0;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top left, transparent 0%, transparent calc(50% - var(--thickness)), var(--lineColor) calc(50% - var(--thickness)), var(--lineColor) calc(50% + var(--thickness)), transparent calc(50% + var(--thickness)), transparent 100%);
    z-index: -1;
  }
</style>
<div class="container">
  <div>Some text <span class="underlined">a short quote</span> and some more text</div>
  <div class="underlined">a rather longer quote</div>
  <div class="underlined">a much much much much much much longer quote</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I started trying to understand it and edited it to pull out a new `--thickness` variable. I still don't understand the `50%`s and how to change them to get the effect I want.  Ideally I'd want an easy-to-implement version of something like https://codepen.io/shadeed/pen/OeNbMO to mimic handwriting. But otherwise I'd want to create a line (rectangle) that has left and right edges that are at angles, and then the whole line itself is slanted slightly upward for short phrases, but the longer a phrase is, the more the rotation of the line approaches "flat". Thanks again.